# Redirect to sub-domain with route parameter in laravel

Tags: subdomain

How can I show for example this route "example.com/parameter" to this "parameter.example.com" for site visitors . 
the back-end of site is laravel 5.3 and web server is Apache. 
I want to use parameter in  laravel controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a subdomain route like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{parameter}.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@showByParameter');
});
```

then in your controller you can do

```
public function showByParameter($parameter)
{
    $user = \App\User::whereParameter($parameter)->firstOrFail();

    return view('users.show', compact('user'));

}
```